# Call Method in Service does not recognize Class working with Stripe Webhooks and Rails 7

Tags: stripe-payments, ruby-on-rails-7

I successfully added the Stripe API to my application by creating a Checkout Session object. I can therefore process payments. The next step is to set up the Webhook which will then change my `payment_status` to `paid`. I am working with a `Booking` class.

I set up a service with a call method in `app/services` which is the following:

```
class StripeCheckoutSessionService
  def call(event)
    booking = Booking.find_by(checkout_session_id: event.data.object.id)
    booking.update(payment_status: 1)

    render json: { state: "processed" }, status: :ok
  end
end
```

Testing the Webhoook locally through Stripes CLI throws me the following error:

```
Booking Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "bookings".* FROM "bookings" WHERE "bookings"."checkout_session_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["checkout_session_id", "cs_test_a1bcREeeCzBEtGQJPUyr5YqCiPtVJYXBItvHEeayYgKP2Rtr1qOih3SJRI"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
↳ app/services/stripe_checkout_session_service.rb:3:in `call'
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 27ms (ActiveRecord: 5.8ms | Allocations: 13382)
 
NoMethodError (undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass):
```

It apparently doesn't recognize my `Class Booking`. All the other requests return `200`:

```
2022-12-21 18:21:49   --> product.created [evt_1MHVzEKr4qTfokMbZmt0oXj6]
2022-12-21 18:21:49  <--  [200] POST http://localhost:3000/update-payment [evt_1MHVzEKr4qTfokMbZmt0oXj6]
2022-12-21 18:21:49   --> price.created [evt_1MHVzFKr4qTfokMbi5lDKURc]
2022-12-21 18:21:49  <--  [200] POST http://localhost:3000/update-payment [evt_1MHVzFKr4qTfokMbi5lDKURc]
2022-12-21 18:21:53   --> checkout.session.completed [evt_1MHVzJKr4qTfokMbQPa7g9Cz]
2022-12-21 18:21:53  <--  [500] POST http://localhost:3000/update-payment [evt_1MHVzJKr4qTfokMbQPa7g9Cz]
2022-12-21 18:21:53   --> charge.succeeded [evt_3MHVzHKr4qTfokMb0CfRjM3Y]
2022-12-21 18:21:53  <--  [200] POST http://localhost:3000/update-payment [evt_3MHVzHKr4qTfokMb0CfRjM3Y]
2022-12-21 18:21:53   --> payment_intent.succeeded [evt_3MHVzHKr4qTfokMb0O5Ivb3a]
2022-12-21 18:21:53  <--  [200] POST http://localhost:3000/update-payment [evt_3MHVzHKr4qTfokMb0O5Ivb3a]
2022-12-21 18:21:53   --> payment_intent.created [evt_3MHVzHKr4qTfokMb04ftdUAI]
2022-12-21 18:21:53  <--  [200] POST http://localhost:3000/update-payment [evt_3MHVzHKr4qTfokMb04ftdUAI]
```

Honestly, I don't know what to try. A `require_relative` of the model is not going to work. I am pretty new to services, so I literally can't understand why it wouldn't recognize my class.

Comment: I think your Booking class is being imported correctly. However, it looks like this line is returning nil: `booking = Booking.find_by(checkout_session_id: event.data.object.id)`

Try logging out the value of "booking" and dig into what exactly the `find_by` method is doing. The error thrown means that "booking" is being set to Nil, so attempting to run the "update" method on "booking" returns an error.

Comment: Hey Laura, thanks for your help! I knew it and I had tried ´.where´ instead and it didn't fix the issue which drove me crazy! In the end I just forgot to restart the server yesterday when I changed from one method to the other. And today it worked with the ´.where´. I don't understand why though.

Comment: laura, could you also please add this as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your Booking class is being imported correctly. However, it looks like this line is returning nil:

```
booking = Booking.find_by(checkout_session_id: event.data.object.id)
```

Try logging out the value of "booking" and dig into what exactly the find_by method is doing. The error thrown means that "booking" is being set to Nil, so attempting to run the "update" method on "booking" returns an error.